# Rookie over here... Need assistance with a Python code conclusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, qualified

Complete this function to return either
"Hello, [name]!" or "Hello there!"
based on the input

```
def say_hello(name):
    name = "Hello there!"

    assert name != "Hello there!"
    # You can print to STDOUT for debugging like you normally would
    print(name)

    # but you need to return the value in order to complete the challenge  
    return "" # TODO: return the correct value
```

I've tried a couple of things but run into errors such as assertion error...
I have completed practice test similar to this before but I'm just drawing a blank here.
Any help with the proper code and how you came to it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the point of assertion here?

Comment: Show us your best attempt instead of just todos. As a hint `name or "there!"` is a pretty good start.

Comment: Why are you reassigning the parameter variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "based on the input"? When should it return `Hello there!`?

Comment: The `assert` will _always_ fail.  I don't understand this code.

Comment: this was my garbage attempt to solve what I figured was an easy question. Will try and post slightly harder material!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will populate the name if one is given and it is not empty ("" evaluates to False)

```py
def say_hello(name=None):
    return f"Hello, {name}!" if name else "Hello there!"
```

Comment: Why not use `"there"` as the default value?

Comment: @Barmar does it really matter? this question is so simple.

Comment: good lord this was driving me a little crazy and you came thru with the simplicity!!

Answer (score 0):

`assert` doesn't make much sense here. You just want to choose one of two return values based on the value of `name`. You can start with adding a default value to the `name` parameter which gives the caller the option of not supplying a name at all and then do a simple truth test.

```
def say_hello(name=None):
    if name:
        return f"Hello, {name}"
    else:
        return "Hello there!"
```